# How do I check if a firebase database value exists?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Realtime Database with Google's Firebase, and I'm trying to check if a child exists.

My database is structured as the following

```
- / (root)
-   /users/
–-    /james/
--    /jake/
-   /rooms/
--    /room1/
---      (room 1 properties)
--    /room2/
---      (room 2 properties)
```

I would like to check if room1 exists.
I have tried the following:

```
let roomName:String = "room1"
roomsDB.child(roomName).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { 
(snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in
    let roomExists:Bool = snap.value != nil ? "TAKEN" : "NOT TAKEN"
 }
```

In accessing `snap.value` it returns a JSON of the properties of that room, but how would I check if the room (`/rooms/room1/`) is there to begin with?

Comment if any clarification is needed

Comment: @Yahoo How would I access it? I can't see where it is in the Swift documentation.

Comment: please refer this . https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

   ref.child("rooms").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild("room1"){

            print("true rooms exist")

        }else{

            print("false room doesn't exist")
        }


    })
```

Comment: this code is for the Firbase 3 (last one ... may 2016)

Comment: you can check also if there is any room with haschildren()  if it is false , it has no room at all ...

Comment: What if the parrent of the object you'd like to check for has a lot of data inside? Will it all be downloaded?

Comment: What about for Firebase 4.0 that was just released May 17 2017!?

Comment: @rhcpfan I think yes, that's why we need to use the query functions of Firebase.

Comment: While this answer works, it downloads more data than needed. Use `ref.child("rooms/room1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){` to reduce the amount of data read from the database. Also see my alternate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494190

Answer (score 30):

While the [answer of @ismael33](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37406072) works, it downloads all the `rooms` to check if `room1` exists.

The following code accomplishes the same, but then only downloads `rooms/room1` to do so:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("rooms/room1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        print("true rooms exist")
    }else{
        print("false room doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Comment: This way is MUCH better. As well as not having to download all the data, if you have restriction in rules like me where you can't read the equivalent of the `room` object, you can go further along the tree without causing issues to check if it does exist.

Answer (score 8):

I have some suggestions by using firebase.You check it from firebase.

We can test for the existence of certain keys within a `DataSnapshot` using its `exists()` method:

> A **DataSnapshot** contains data from a Firebase database location. Any
>   time you read data from a Firebase database, you receive the data as a
>   DataSnapshot.
>
> A DataSnapshot is passed to the event callbacks you attach with `on()`
>   or `once()`. You can extract the contents of the snapshot as a
>   JavaScript object by calling its `val()` method. Alternatively, you can
>   traverse into the snapshot by calling `child()` to return child
>   snapshots (which you could then call `val()` on).
>
> A DataSnapshot is an efficiently-generated, immutable copy of the data
>   at a database location. They cannot be modified and will never change.
>   To modify data, you always use a Firebase reference directly.

**exists()** - Returns true if this DataSnapshot contains any data. It is slightly more efficient than using snapshot.`val() !== null.`

Example from firebase documentation(javascript example)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users/fred");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var a = snapshot.exists();
  // a === true

  var b = snapshot.child("rooms").exists();
  // b === true

  var c = snapshot.child("rooms/room1").exists();
  // c === true

  var d = snapshot.child("rooms/room0").exists();
  // d === false (because there is no "rooms/room0" child in the data snapshot)
});
```

Also please refer this [page](https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949)(already mentioned in my comment)

Here there is an example using java.

```
Firebase userRef= new Firebase(USERS_LOCATION);
userRef.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.getValue() !== null) {
            //user exists, do something
        } else {
            //user does not exist, do something else
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
    }
});
```

I hope you got an idea now.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I was looking for Firebase 3. I should have specified. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check snapshot.exists value.

```
NSString *roomId = @"room1";
FIRDatabaseReference *refUniqRoom = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference]
                                      child:@"rooms"]
                                     child:roomId];

[refUniqRoom observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
                            withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    bool isExists = snapshot.exists;
    NSLog(@"%d", isExists);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of them So simple and easy ...
Which way you like

```
ValueEventListener responseListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override    
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // Do stuff        
        } else {
            // Do stuff        
        }
    }

    @Override    
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

FirebaseUtil.getResponsesRef().child(postKey).addValueEventListener(responseListener);
```

---

```
function go() {
  var userId = prompt('Username?', 'Guest');
  checkIfUserExists(userId);
}

var USERS_LOCATION = 'https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users';

function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
  if (exists) {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' exists!');
  } else {
    alert('user ' + userId + ' does not exist!');
  }
}

// Tests to see if /users/<userId> has any data. 
function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
  var usersRef = new Firebase(USERS_LOCATION);
  usersRef.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
  });
}
```

---

```
Firebase userRef= new Firebase(USERS_LOCATION);
userRef.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.getValue() !== null) {
            //user exists, do something
        } else {
            //user does not exist, do something else
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
users = new HashMap<>();
                users.put("UserID", milisec);
                users.put("UserName", username);
                users.put("UserEmailID", email);
                users.put("UserPhoneNumber", phoneno);
                users.put("UserPassword", hiddenEditPassword);
                users.put("UserDateTime", new Timestamp(new Date()));
                users.put("UserProfileImage", " ");

                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(phoneno).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Already User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                                    .document(phoneno).set(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });`
enter code here
```

Comment: Super Solution User Login