# check if key exists firebase 4 and swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I check if a key exists in Firebase? I have seen this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405149/how-do-i-check-if-a-firebase-database-value-exists), but it's for Firebase 3, and it doesn't work for my situation. So for my case, I want to check to see if a username exists, and if it does, then don't register a user, but if it doesn't then register. I have something along the lines of this:

```
        let usersDB = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
        var taken = false

        usersDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild(username) {
                taken = true
                self.errorLabel.text = "Username already taken."
            }
        })

        if !taken {
            // Email registration
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                } else {
                    // Allows for username log in
                    usersDB.child(username).setValue(["email" : user?.email])
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToGroups", sender: self)
                }
            })
        }
```

The `observeSingleEvent` is what the previous similar post's solution was, but it only runs after I add a child on this line `usersDB.child(username).setValue(["email" : user?.email])`, **it never runs before.** Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like an issue with handling asynchronous calls. `if !taken` is very likely going to be checked before data is returned from `observeSingleEvent` because it's asynchronous, so the rest of the code will continue to run. One option is to move `if !taken` into the closure, like this:

```
    let usersDB = Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(username)")
    var taken = false

    usersDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            taken = true
            self.errorLabel.text = "Username already taken."
        }
        if !taken {
            // Email registration
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                } else {
                    // Allows for username log in
                    usersDB.child(username).setValue(["email" : user?.email])
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToGroups", sender: self)
                }
            })
        }
    })
```